# Is there a way to remove empty line break from a concatenation result?

Tags: excel-formula, concatenation, trim, substitution

I'm concatenating cells from different rows into one cell, using line break `(char(10))`. Because cells with empty fields are being concatenated, this is adding empty lines in the process. Is there a way to modify my formula in order to remove those empty lines?

```
    =IF(COUNTBLANK(A2);"";CONCATENATE(E2; CHAR(10); D2; CHAR(10); C2; CHAR(10); F2; CHAR(10); G2; CHAR(10); H2; CHAR(10); I2))
```

[image: results with empty lines]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your specific order that you use is not important and you have OFFICE 365 Excel then you can use TEXTJOIN:

```
=IF(A2="","",TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,C2:I2)
```

---

If it matters and you have OFFICE 365 then you can use TEXTJOIN as an array formula:

```
=IF(A2="","",TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,5,6,7},E2,D2,C2,F2,G2,H2,I2))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

---

If you do not have Office 365 then you will need to contatenate a string of IFs

```
IF(E2<>"",CHAR(10) & E2,"") & IF(D2<>"",CHAR(10) & D2,"") & ...
```

Wrap that in a mid to remove the first `CHAR(10)`

```
MID(IF(E2<>"",CHAR(10) & E2,"") & IF(D2<>"",CHAR(10) & D2,"") & ...,2,999)
```